# Getting a collection of objects based on ActiveRecord assoc and values

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have two models/tables, Schools and Reviews. I would like to get a collection of School objects based on a minimum number of reviews and then the average of a column on the review table. Currently, my query works well and returns all schools in order from 5.0 avg to nulls last and looks like this:

```
School.joins('LEFT JOIN reviews ON schools.id = reviews.school_id')
      .group('schools.id')
      .order('AVG(reviews.overall_experience_rating) DESC NULLS LAST')
```

however, I'd like to be able to have a limiter in here that only selects the school object if it has 15 or more reviews, something like:

```
where("school.reviews.count >= 15")
```

The association between the two models in active record is a one to many relationship. Any thoughts?

Comment: if you setup your relations correctly, make your *join* look nicer: `.joins(:reviews)` - rails will automatically do the magic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've figured out that use of `having` in ActiveRecord is what I need:

```
School.joins(:reviews)
  .group('schools.id')
  .having("COUNT(reviews) > ?", 15)
  .order('AVG(reviews.overall_experience_rating) DESC NULLS LAST')
```